# How can I get a shapefile from a postgis query?

Tags: postgis, shapefile, gdal

My data is in a PostGIS database. I would like to generate a shapefile from a query. How can I do that?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The recommended way to do this is using the **pgsql2shp** utility, which should be installed with PostGIS. Note that you must include the geometry column in the query.

```
$ pgsql2shp -f <path to output shapefile> -h <hostname> -u <username> -P <password> databasename "<query>"
```

Example (creates `qds_cnt.shp` in current directory):

```
$ pgsql2shp -f qds_cnt -h localhost -u postgres -P password gisdb "SELECT sp_count, geom FROM grid50_rsa WHERE province = 'Gauteng'"

Initializing... 
Done (postgis major version: 2).
Output shape: Polygon
Dumping: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX [1947 rows].
```

If you wanted to save a whole table as a shapefile, just use the table name as the query.

You can also use the **ogr2ogr** utility, but it has more dependencies so should not be the first option. If you are determined, the equivalent command would be:

```
$ ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" qds_cnt.shp PG:"host=localhost user=postgres dbname=gisdb password=password" -sql "SELECT sp_count, geom FROM grid50_rsa WHERE province = 'Gauteng'"
```

**See also**

- [Linfinity PostGIS import/export guide](http://manual.linfiniti.com/en/postgis/import_export.html)
- [Converting PostGIS table to Shapefile in Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16737/how-to-convert-postgis-table-to-shapefile-in-python)

Comment: Is it possible to use `pgsql2shp` to export a view to a shapefile?

Answer (score 16):

I don't have enough reputation points to comment on rudivonstaden's answer but I would add that writing sql commands in uppercase letters matters to pgsql2shp.

For instance, this won't work:

```
$ pgsql2shp -f qds_cnt -h localhost -u postgres -P password gisdb "Select sp_count, geom from grid50_rsa where province = 'Gauteng'"
```

whereas this will work:

```
$ pgsql2shp -f qds_cnt -h localhost -u postgres -P password gisdb "SELECT sp_count, geom FROM grid50_rsa WHERE province = 'Gauteng'"
```

Answer (score 9):

Depending on the piece of data you want to export, another way is to use qgis or a similar product : there you open a connection ot postgis and select the data you're interested in; then you save as shapefile...

If you want to export automatically and/or large parts of data, rudivonstaden gave appropriate solutions!