# Overlaying spatial polygon with grid and checking in which grid element specific coordinates are located using R

Tags: r, vector-grid, point-in-polygon

How can one **use R** to

1. **split a shapefile** in 200 meter squares/sub-polygons,
2. **plot this grid** (incl. ID numbers for each square) over the original map below, and
3. evaluate in which square specific **geographic coordinates are located**.

I am a beginner in GIS and this is perhaps a basic question, but I haven't found a tutorial on how to do this in R.

What I have done so far is loading a shapefile of NYC and plotting some exemplary geographic coordinates.

**I am looking for an example (R code) how to this with the data below.**

```
# Load packages 
library(maptools)

# Download shapefile for NYC
# OLD URL (no longer working)
# shpurl <- "http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/download/bytes/nybb_13a.zip"
shpurl <- "https://www1.nyc.gov/assets/planning/download/zip/data-maps/open-data/nybb_13a.zip"

tmp    <- tempfile(fileext=".zip")
download.file(shpurl, destfile=tmp)
files <- unzip(tmp, exdir=getwd())

# Load & plot shapefile
shp <- readShapePoly(files[grep(".shp$", files)])
plot(shp)

# Define coordinates 
points_of_interest <- data.frame(y=c(919500, 959500, 1019500, 1049500, 1029500, 989500), 
                 x =c(130600, 150600, 180600, 198000, 248000, 218000),
                 id  =c("A"), stringsAsFactors=F)

# Plot coordinates
points(points_of_interest$y, points_of_interest$x, pch=19, col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/17801398/287948

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here is an example using a `SpatialGrid` object:

```
### read shapefile
library("rgdal")
shp <- readOGR("nybb_13a", "nybb")

proj4string(shp)  # units us-ft
# [1] "+proj=lcc +lat_1=40.66666666666666 +lat_2=41.03333333333333 
# +lat_0=40.16666666666666 +lon_0=-74 +x_0=300000 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83
# +units=us-ft +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"

### define coordinates and convert to SpatialPointsDataFrame
poi <- data.frame(x=c(919500, 959500, 1019500, 1049500, 1029500, 989500),
                  y=c(130600, 150600, 180600, 198000, 248000, 218000),
                  id="A", stringsAsFactors=F)
coordinates(poi) <- ~ x + y
proj4string(poi) <- proj4string(shp)

### define SpatialGrid object
bb <- bbox(shp)
cs <- c(3.28084, 3.28084)*6000  # cell size 6km x 6km (for illustration)
                                # 1 ft = 3.28084 m
cc <- bb[, 1] + (cs/2)  # cell offset
cd <- ceiling(diff(t(bb))/cs)  # number of cells per direction
grd <- GridTopology(cellcentre.offset=cc, cellsize=cs, cells.dim=cd)
grd
# cellcentre.offset 923018 129964
# cellsize           19685  19685
# cells.dim              8      8

sp_grd <- SpatialGridDataFrame(grd,
                               data=data.frame(id=1:prod(cd)),
                               proj4string=CRS(proj4string(shp)))
summary(sp_grd)
# Object of class SpatialGridDataFrame
# Coordinates:
#      min     max
# x 913175 1070655
# y 120122  277602
# Is projected: TRUE
# ...
```

Now you can use the implemented `over`-method to obtain the cell IDs:

```
over(poi, sp_grd)
#   id
# 1 57
# 2 51
# 3 38
# 4 39
# 5 14
# 6 28
```

To plot the shapefile and the grid with the cell IDs:

```
library("lattice")
spplot(sp_grd, "id",
       panel = function(...) {
         panel.gridplot(..., border="black")
         sp.polygons(shp)
         sp.points(poi, cex=1.5)
         panel.text(...)
       })
```

[image: spplot1]

or without colour/colour key:

```
library("lattice")
spplot(sp_grd, "id", colorkey=FALSE,
       panel = function(...) {
         panel.gridplot(..., border="black", col.regions="white")
         sp.polygons(shp)
         sp.points(poi, cex=1.5)
         panel.text(..., col="red")
       })
```

[image: spplot2]

Comment: This looks like an answer to me, but in case you are looking for something different.  Try the r tag in stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=R+tag

Comment: @rcs this code looks just like what I am trying to do but my shapefile is in a different projection:

`proj4string (DK_reg1)
[1] "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"`

does anyone have any suggestions on how to break this shapefiles of this projection to 1000 equal sized grid cells? and then randomly select 100 of them and highlight them?

Answer (score 13):

The New York dataset provided in the question is no longer available for download. I use the nc dataset from sf package to demonstrate a solution using sf package:

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

# read nc polygon data and transform to UTM 
nc <- st_read(system.file('shape/nc.shp', package = 'sf')) %>%
  st_transform(32617)

# random sample of 5 points
pts <- st_sample(nc, size = 5) %>% st_sf

# create 50km grid - here you can substitute 200 for 50000
grid_50 <- st_make_grid(nc, cellsize = c(50000, 50000)) %>% 
  st_sf(grid_id = 1:length(.))

# create labels for each grid_id
grid_lab <- st_centroid(grid_50) %>% cbind(st_coordinates(.))

# view the sampled points, polygons and grid
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc, fill = 'white', lwd = 0.05) +
  geom_sf(data = pts, color = 'red', size = 1.7) + 
  geom_sf(data = grid_50, fill = 'transparent', lwd = 0.3) +
  geom_text(data = grid_lab, aes(x = X, y = Y, label = grid_id), size = 2) +
  coord_sf(datum = NA)  +
  labs(x = "") +
  labs(y = "")

# which grid square is each point in?
pts %>% st_join(grid_50, join = st_intersects) %>% as.data.frame

#>   grid_id                 geometry
#> 1      55 POINT (359040.7 3925435)
#> 2      96   POINT (717024 4007464)
#> 3      91 POINT (478906.6 4037308)
#> 4      40 POINT (449671.6 3901418)
#> 5      30 POINT (808971.4 3830231)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I updated the link in my question to relfect the changes on their webpage. Now it should work again.

Comment: I really need to start using the `sf` package. This is awesome!

Comment: Is there an easy way to only plot the grid cells that intersect with the state polygon?

Comment: st_intersection(grid_50, nc) should do it

Comment: Is there a way to replicate the same, but the points in the centre of each grid, so a grid is being drawn with the lat/long as the centre of the grid @sebdalgarno

Answer (score 3):

If you have not looked at the R raster package, it has tools to convert to/from vector GIS objects so you should be able to a) create a raster (grid) with 200x200m cells and b) convert it to a set of polygons with a logical id of some kind.  From there I would look at the sp package to help with intersecting the points and the polygon grid.  This http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/vignettes/over.pdf page might be a good start.  Wandering through the sp package docs you might be able to start with the SpatialGrid-class and just skip the raster part entirely.

Answer (score -1):

The "GIS universe" is complex and have many standards that your data must be compliant. All "GIS tools" interoperates by [GIS-standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Geospatial_Consortium). All "serious GIS data" today (2014) are  [stored in a database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_database).

The best way to "use R" in a GIS context, with other [FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software) tools, is embedded into SQL. The best tools are [PostgreSQL 9.X](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/external-pl.html) (see [PL/R](http://www.joeconway.com/plr/)) and [PostGIS](http://postgis.org/).

---

You answer:

- To import/export shape files: use [`shp2pgsql` and `pgsql2shp`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/55207/7505).
- To "split a shape file in 200 meter squares/sub-polygons": see `ST_SnapToGrid()`, `ST_AsRaster()`, etc. We need understand better your needs to express into a "recipe".
- you say that need "geographic coordinates are located" .. perhaps `ST_Centroid()` of the squares (?)... You can express "more mathematically" so I understand.

... Perhaps you not need any raster convertion, only a matrix of regurlar-sampled points.

---

A primitive way is use R without *PL/R*,  in a your usual external compiler: only convert your polygons and export as shape or as WKT (see `ST_AsText`), then convert data with [awk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awk) or another filter to the R format.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I would strongly prefer a solution which relies completely on R and existing packages. When I am able to split the shape file in 200m*200m subpolygons I can check with `point.in.polygon` which coordinates are in which polygons. My problem is to split the original shapefile  in those sub-polygons.