# Calculate centre point of SpatialGrid object

Tags: r, coordinates, grids-graticules, centroids

I am using R and have a `SpatialGrid` object similar to the example from this question:

[Overlay a spatial polygon with a grid and check in which grid element specific coordinates are located](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88830/overlay-a-spatial-polygon-with-a-grid-and-check-in-which-grid-element-specific-c)

```
## read shapefile
library("rgdal")
shp <- readOGR("nybb_13a", "nybb")

proj4string(shp)  # units us-ft
# [1] "+proj=lcc +lat_1=40.66666666666666 +lat_2=41.03333333333333 
# +lat_0=40.16666666666666 +lon_0=-74 +x_0=300000 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83
# +units=us-ft +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"

### define coordinates and convert to SpatialPointsDataFrame
poi <- data.frame(x=c(919500, 959500, 1019500, 1049500, 1029500, 989500),
              y=c(130600, 150600, 180600, 198000, 248000, 218000),
              id="A", stringsAsFactors=F)
coordinates(poi) <- ~ x + y
proj4string(poi) <- proj4string(shp)

### define SpatialGrid object
bb <- bbox(shp)
cs <- c(3.28084, 3.28084)*6000  # cell size 6km x 6km (for illustration)
                            # 1 ft = 3.28084 m
cc <- bb[, 1] + (cs/2)  # cell offset
cd <- ceiling(diff(t(bb))/cs)  # number of cells per direction
grd <- GridTopology(cellcentre.offset=cc, cellsize=cs, cells.dim=cd)
grd
# cellcentre.offset 923018 129964
# cellsize           19685  19685
# cells.dim              8      8

sp_grd <- SpatialGridDataFrame(grd,
                           data=data.frame(id=1:prod(cd)),
                           proj4string=CRS(proj4string(shp)))
```

I have a `SpatialGrid` rather than `SpatialGridDataFrame`, so:

```
new_sp_grd <- SpatialGrid(grd,proj4string=CRS(proj4string(shp)))
```

I now want to calculate the centre coordinates of each grid cell, so that I can calculate the distance between this point and a variety of `SpatialLines` and `SpatialPolygons` objects.

Can anyone suggest how to do this? There is help for finding the centre of a polygon, but not a grid, and functions such as `gCentroid` from the `rgeos` package do not work on `SpatialGrids`.

Comment: wondering if this helps at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37017854/create-points-from-a-grid-using-r

Comment: AFAIK SpatialGrid contains a regular grid, so you can easily calculate each cell address by getting the `value(X/Y) = bbox min X and Y + cellsize/2 offset`. Then every cell in the grid will have the coordinates: `X = valueX + cellsize*column` and `Y = valueY + cellsize*row`

Comment: Thanks for good informations.
I have questions. The unit of cellsize in GridTopology is [ft]??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`coordinates(new_sp_grd)` returns the center coordinates of each cell.
Here is a simple example:

```
library("sp")
grid <- SpatialGrid(GridTopology(c(0, 0), c(1, 1), c(5, 4)))

# get coordinates of center coordinates of each cell
grid_ctr <- coordinates(grid)

plot(grid, axes=TRUE)
points(grid_ctr, col="red", pch=16)
```

[image: grid plot]

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this enough?

```
x <- 1:(cd[1,1])*cc['x']
y <- 1:(cd[1,2])*cc['y']

grid_cells_centre <- data.frame(x=rep(x, length(y)), y=rep(y, each=length(x)))
```