# Drawing a grid over a Map in R

Tags: r, grids-graticules

I am a newbie to R and I want to divide a country map into **grids** so that I can come to a decision according to the **latitude and longitude values** which grid am I residing.

I am looking for an example (R code) how to this.

Comment: See the raster package. Create a raster() with the offset and resolution you want, and use cellFromXY(ras, xy). If you want to tile the polygon map (you don't really say) see https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/geoaxe/ for one way.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to draw gridlines on a map, have a look at https://edzer.github.io/sp/, and especially at the `sp::gridlines` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a polygon fishnet offline using GIS tools and plot the data along with fishnet.Alternatively a complete R-base solution is provided in SE link here [Overlay a spatial polygon with a grid and check in which grid element specific coordinates are located](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88830/overlay-a-spatial-polygon-with-a-grid-and-check-in-which-grid-element-specific-c)

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Durga .But the link is for a shape file where my file is a google map.Could you please help me?

Comment: You should add this detail about requirements to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way to make that is using the map.grid() function. Pls visit the page https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mapproj/versions/1.2-5/topics/map.grid. The documentation is very simple and obvious. Let me know if you have issues still/